# Entity Framework Core - Creating multiple identical records with a given object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I receive data of

1. a list of items and
2. ONE person from user input

The order table will have links to item and person. I will need to create order record linking each item and the person. However, I cannot simply create one person record and associate all the items with him. Due to compliance requirement, I need to create duplicate person records and associate each item with a separate but identical person record, for example, this is what I need:

I get items: car, tv; person: john. I will need to write data into database and create orders like this (seq fields are autogenerated IDENTITY columns)

`Item` table:

```
id    name
-----------
 1    car
 2    tv
```

`Person` table:

```
id    name
-----------
 1    john
 2    john
```

`Order` table:

```
id   person_ref   item_ref
--------------------------
 1       1           1
 2       2           2
```

The `Person` and `Items` objects are from user input. I should get one person only and multiple items. Below is the code, Person, Item and Order are the tables and they are linked through foreign key order->item, order->person

```
[BindProperty]
public Person Person { get; set; } = null!;

[BindProperty]
public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = null!;


using (var context = new Db())
{
    foreach (Item item in Items)
    {
        Order o = new Order();
                                
        o.ItemRefNavigation = item;
        o.PersonRefNavigation = Person;
                                
        context.Orders.Add(o);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

However, this creates the following records

`Item` table:

```
id   name
-----------
 1   car
 2   tv
```

`Person` table:

```
id   name
---------
 1   john
```

`Order` table:

```
id   person_ref   item_ref
---------------------------
 1       1           1
 2       1           2
```

If for each item I manually create a new `Person` and populate it with `Person` data, I do get multiple records in person table, however, only one person record is used to create order record, it looks like this

`Item` table:

```
id   name
---------
 1   car
 2   tv
```

`Person` table:

```
id   name
-----------
 1   john
 2   john
```

`Order` table:

```
id   person_ref   item_ref
---------------------------
 1       1           1
 2       1           2
```

How can I get identical person records created and linked to each item? I am new to Entity Framework. Could you please help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EF works with references, so if you reference the same Person instance they will link to the same row. If you want distinct Persons with the same name (Id #1 and #2) then you need to ensure orders are created with a new Person instance:

```
using (var context = new Db())
{
    foreach (Item item in Items)
    {
        Order o = new Order();
                                
        o.ItemRefNavigation = item;
        o.PersonRefNavigation = new Person { name = Person.Name };
                                
        context.Orders.Add(o);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

That should give you a 1-1-1 & 2-2-2 for OrderId-Person-ItemId

This is the opposite to the problem that most people encounter with EF where they are expecting two instances with the name "John" to refer to the same record where EF creates the two separate rows for each instance. References mean everything to EF.

For larger objects with multiple values etc. you can use a Mapper to perform a full copy into a new instance.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I did this Persion x = new Person();
context.Entry(x).CurrentValues.SetValues(Person); o.PersonRefNavigation = x; and it seems to be working also. is it correct?

Comment: Yes, this will work for entities as long as they don't have any navigation properties that you need to clone as well. For instance if Person has an Address that you want a new copy of as well. In those cases you need to do the same sort of thing going through any/all references you want to clone as well.